# Issue with Shiny-Gadget in RStudio- does not launch/run - no error returned

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am attempting to create my first basic Shiny Gadget. However, when I try to run the Shiny gadget function in question, it just prints the R function contents in the console window but doesn't actually run the function itself.

In troubleshooting, if I run the ui & server component seperately and then run the runGadget command the gadget does run so something is not initialising from the function or is being blocked.

I have searched the web for issues with running Shiny apps but there could not find any posts. Also no error is return to give any clue when this happens.

So for example when I attempt to run the first example:

```
library(miniUI)

myFirstGadget <- function() {
        ui <- miniPage(
                gadgetTitleBar("My First Gadget")
                )
        server <- function(input, output, session) { 
                # The Done button closes the app 
                observeEvent(input$done, { 
                        stopApp()
                })
        } 
        runGadget(ui, server) 
        }

myFirstGadget
```

I get the following returned:

```
> myFirstGadget
function() {
        ui <- miniPage(
                gadgetTitleBar("My First Gadget")
                )
        server <- function(input, output, session) { 
                # The Done button closes the app 
                observeEvent(input$done, { 
                        stopApp()
                })
        } 
        runGadget(ui, server) 
        }
```

instead of the "listening on http://127..0.0.1:7057" and the launch of the gadget.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the last line of your code from `myFirstGadget` to `myFirstGadget()` and it will run. When you just used myFirstGadget, it shows you the function's code. You need the parentheses to run the function/your gadget.

```
myFirstGadget <- function() {
  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My First Gadget")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    # The Done button closes the app 
    observeEvent(input$done, { 
      stopApp()
    })
  } 
  runGadget(ui, server) 
}

myFirstGadget() # <---- the only line that I edited
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks very much for the feedback. That makes complete sense. Schoolboy error on my part. Kind regards, Paddy